# BadImageFormatException when CancellationTokenSource is declared at class level

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-framework-version, cancellationtokensource, .net-4.7.2

I have a class in which there is a need for a long running task, which needs to be cancelled on a button click (called from the UI thread). For this to work, I created a CancellationTokenSource at the class level. When the long running task has to be started, I get the Cancellationtoken from the source and pass it to the task. In the method for disconnect/cancel the task. I call the Cancel on the cancellation token source.
The problem is when I patch the application with these changes, on clicking the button which starts the task, it crashes with a BadImageFormatException.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public class TaskRunner
{
   private CancellationTokenSource ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   private Task _task; 
   private bool _isTaskPerforming = true; 
  
   public async void BeginTask()
   {
     var ct = ctSource.Token;

     await PerformTask(ct);
   }
   
   private async Task PerformTask(CancellationToken ct)
   {
      _task = Task.Run(() =>
         {
            while(_isTaskPerforming)
            {
               //Perform task related functions
               //Check for cancellation
               if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   _isTaskPerforming = false;
                   //other cleanup
               }
            }
         },ct);
   }

   public void CancelTask()
   {
      ctSource.Cancel();
   }
}
```

This is the minimal code that I can share. Both BeginTask and CancelTask will be called by the WPF button click event handlers from the application that references this DLL. But when I patch this DLL the application crashes with a BadImageFormatException.

Comment: A `BadImageFormatException` generally indicates that you are loading an assembly in unexpected format. It's usually the result of a 32-64 bit-ness issue. I don't think it's a cancelation token problem; it's a DLL loading issue. What do you mean when you say _patch this dll_?

Comment: By patching, I mean copy it into the system where this application is running. If I make any other changes, the program runs fine with the same bit-ness that I build it in. The exception comes only when I include this CancellationToken code.

Comment: Generally the term _patch_ implies modifying a PE file (an exe or a dll). If assemblies (dlls) are being loaded dynamically, bitness issues can still show up dependingon the path through your code. The Fusion Log Viewer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) may be able to help you figure stuff out